# jQuery datepicker maxDate issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have the following code for jQuery datepicker

```
        $('#startDate').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            maxDate: '0'
        })
        .on('changeDate', function (ev) {
            $('#startDate').datepicker('hide');
        });
```

It launches in a Bootstrap modal.  It is working as expected apart from the maxDate - I want to restrict user from entering any date in the future - is there something I am missing?  I also tried `maxDate : new Date()`  which also did not work.  And I did a hard reload and have checked Dev Tools and I can see the java-script in the rendered markup is as expected.

Updated with full html markup.

```
<input id="startDate" placeholder="Select Date" data-provide="datepicker" class="datepicker ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" readonly="readonly" style="cursor:auto; background-color:white" ng-model="item.startDate" ng-change="startDateChanged(item.startDate)">
```

Using jQuery 1.10.2 and Angular 1.4.1

Comment: What you have is correct, and should give the desired behaviour. Do you have a link to where it is not working?

Comment: maxDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "getDate" );

Comment: Site note, this will not prevent users from typing future dates into the field, but will simply prevent them picking those future dates from the datepicker itself.

Comment: works fine for me, but as MasNotsram says, it only stops them picking future dates in the UI, not typing them in the box. Also, your date format is setting is incorrect, it should be `dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"` - see http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Comment: lastly, you don't need the ".on" method - the picker will hide itself automatically when someone selects a date. That code is redundant.

Comment: Can we add the jquery-ui tag to this question?

Comment: @ADyson - the picker does not hide for me automatically when a date is picked - I am using jquery-1.10.2.  What would be required to prevent the user from typing a date into the box?

Comment: it hides fine for me. (jquery 2.2.3 and jquery-ui 1.12). But it's always worked fine for me on earlier versions too. Anyway, you don't want to stop the user from typing in the box entirely - that's anti-user, in particular it's bad for people who use their keyboard over their mouse, or people with accessibility issues. You just want to stop them putting in a date larger than the maxDate. This should be part of your general model validation (both server and client side). The maxDate property on the datepicker is just a nice-to-have extra. You can't rely on it

Comment: note I am using angular as well - I added readonly to the html as that works for me for the app I am developing.  Updated the question with the full markup that is rendered on screen

Comment: what does the `startDateChanged(item.startDate)` function do?

Comment: @ADyson - realised the error - the library another dev added was the bootstrap datepicker js and not the jquery one.  The property is endDate and when I looked at the documentation on - https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#autoclose - there is even an autoclose which should have been used and not the on event - its too early in the morning is my excuse :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will work for you

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    maxDate: 0
});
```

Comment: neither "format" nor "endDate" are properties of the jQuery datepicker. (see http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) This answer will not help.

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought you are using Jquery bootstrap datepicker

this will surely work for you :- 

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
 format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        maxDate: 0
});

here you can check [testing](https://jsfiddle.net/g5vypyaj/)

Comment: @gauravjoshi - you were correct in you original answer and if you had have puta note in saying was I using bootstrap datepicker along with you code it might have been more clear as to the properties you were using - it is unfortunate you were automatically down voted

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat to be fair the original question clearly states that jQuery datepicker was being used. Therefore my comment is based on that assumption. There was no reliable way to tell from the question that it might not be. It's only later that you realised this wasn't the case by looking elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to Prevent the user from typing a date into the text box then add `readonly='true'` in your Textbox.

**HTML**

```
<input id="Datepicker" type="text" readonly='true' />
```

**Demo :** [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/1juozmdn/6/)

Comment: This is anti-user. in particular it's bad for people who use their keyboard over their mouse, or people with accessibility issues. For instance I know lots of typists who tab through forms and type the values into them, rather than using the mouse to select every field. Such people would find this incredibly annoying. Also, your demo hasn't corrected the mistake with the non-existent `format` property, or the incorrect format string

Comment: @ADyson  Good Thought I Agree With U! But his need Prevent the user from typing a date into the text box, So based on his question i posted this answer.

Comment: In the original question the OP never asked for preventing the user from typing in the box. The confusion was around why the datepicker wasn't working (which turned out to be because they were using a different plugin to the one they thought they were). OP then suggested preventing typing in the box in the comments as a workaround, but I made the same comment there, that this is bad for usability - instead validation rules should be used to ensure that acceptable values are entered.

Answer (score 0):

Lesson learned is to search what libraries other devs add to the project and dont assume its the one you have used in the past - I have used jQuery Datepicker in nearly every other place I have developed.  This particular Dev had included bootstrap js datepicker.  The options for it were endDate and also there is an option for autoclose so I can even get rid of the 'on' event handler which was doing the hiding

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html